# How do I write a .Net Regular Expression to match from the end of line back

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following line of text

```
Reference=*\G{7B35DDAC-FFE2-4435-8A15-CF5C70F23459}#1.0#0#..\..\..\bin\App Components\AcmeFormEngine.dll#ACME Form Engine
```

and wish to grab the following as two separate capture groups:

```
AcmeFormEngine.dll
ACME Form Engine
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I voted for tomalask's non-regex approach.**
However if you HAD to do it with regex, I think you need something like this

```
\\([^\\/?"<>|]+?)\#([^\\/?"<>|]+?)[\r\n]*$
```

This will allow things like - and _ which are valid in filenames, Its 2 identical groups (each excluding invalid chars for win32 filenames) beginning with a slash, delimited by a # and at the end of the line (the $). Assuming second group is also a valid win32 filename..
I saw some ugly boxes in the matched second group, the [\r\n]* keeps them away.

```
e.g. F5C70F23459}#1.0#0#..\..\..\bin\App Components\Acme_Form-Engine.dll#ACME Form Engine
group#1 => Acme_Form-Engine.dll
group#2 => ACME Form Engine
```

In short this is arcane.. avoid if possible.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sincere of the string format, you can also solve that in an earthbound manner, without regex: Take everything after the last index of '\', and split that at '#'.

Comment: And more efficient since we only need to do character comparison and avoid the overhead of the state machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    Regex regex = new Regex(
    @"\\(?<filename>[\w\.]+)\#(?<comment>[\w ]+)$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

Comment: Does the hash really need escaping? What special meaning does it have?

Comment: # seems to stand for comment :) I think

Comment: Silly .NET regexes. Fixed mine now.

Comment: this is broken if you have - or _ in the filename

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex r = new Regex("\\(.+?)\#(.+?)$");
```

Non-greedy multiplicities are great.

`'$'`: Match the end of the string.

`"\#(.+?)"`: Match everything back from the end of the string till the first '#' character and return that in a capture.

`"\\(.+?)"`: Same again, except with an escaped '\'.

Comment: upvote because it's the shorted expression and you explained how/why it works